# Update password on active directory using PHP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, password-encryption, change-password

I connect, make validation and even updates like dyplayName and ipphone. But when I try to update the unicodePwd, I'm getting the error:

> 53 - Server is unwilling to perform

When I try the following code:

```
function hash_password( $newPassword ) {
    $newPassword = "\"" . $newPassword . "\"";
    $len = strlen( $newPassword );
    $newPassw = "";
    for ( $i = 0; $i < $len; $i++ ) {
        $newPassw .= "{$newPassword {$i}}\000";
    }
    $userdata["unicodePwd"] = $newPassw;
    return $userdata;
}

public function _login($pwd) {
    $link = ldap_connect('123.123.123.123');
    ldap_set_option($link, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
    ldap_set_option($link, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
    if (!(@ldap_bind($link, 'company\\' . $user_ldap, $pwd_ldap))) {
        //show error
    }
    $filter = "(samaccountname=" . $user . ")";
    $result = ldap_search($link, $ldap_dn, $filter);//, $attrs);
    $entries = ldap_get_entries($link, $result);
    $dn = $entries[0]["dn"];

    $entry = $this->hash_password($pwd);

    if (ldap_modify($link,$dn,$entry) === false){
        // show error 
        // It always hit this part on the code
    }
    ldap_close($link);
}
```

I tried others encrypt format, that I found on the internet, none worked. Also tried the password without encryption, no result.

How can I change the current password of a user that has it expired/have to change on the next login?

Comment: btw, I know what the error 53 stands for: "Indicates that the LDAP server cannot process the request because of server-defined restrictions. This error is returned for the following reasons: The add entry request violates the server's structure rules...OR...The modify attribute request specifies attributes that users cannot modify...OR...Password restrictions prevent the action...OR...Connection restrictions prevent the action." - [source](http://wiki.servicenow.com/index.php?title=LDAP_Error_Codes#gsc.tab=0). I just don't know how to workaround/fix it

Comment: The password that I use for test is Mars2022 (min 6 characters, 1 upper, 1 lower, 1 number)

Comment: Look in the logs and see why your AD server rejected it.

Comment: @Sammitch when I use `LDAP_OPT_DIAGNOSTIC_MESSAGE` I got the error "0000001F: SvcErr: DSID-031A12D2, problem 5003 (WILL_NOT_PERFORM), data 0"

Comment: Your AD server's logs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be on a [secured connection to modify a password](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc223248.aspx).

Add the following before you call `ldap_bind()`:

```
ldap_start_tls($link);
```

This is a good idea even if you aren't trying to change a password as otherwise your bind operation is cleartext and can be sniffed.

Comment: It gives me the following: `TLS error -8179:Peer's Certificate issuer is not recognized.`. and the PHP Warning: `Message:  ldap_start_tls(): Unable to start TLS: Connect error`